# Passing Data across NiFi Processors

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a situation involving custom processors participating in various stages of the ETL pipeline:

`Processor_1 -> Processor_2 -> Processor_3`

For some use cases, Processor_3 needs to refer to the original data input to Processor_1. There is the concept of parent reference in the flowfile definition.

The crude method is to pass the orginal data with the flow file from Processor_1 to Processor_2 to Processor_3. Is there a mechanism for downstream processors to reference the original data?

Comment: What is the nature of the data you are trying to reference downstream?  Typically, values of importance are extracted out as attributes to be used by follow on processors.

Comment: True; but I want to refer to the original message when the grammar fails.

Answer (score 0):

Neel, what does the object structure of your content look like? Could you create an original and modified version within the flowfile contents that you could access, if needed? Then down stream extract the version you need?

Alternatively, you could stuff the original contents in an attribute and reference them, if needed in processor 3.

There might be a NIFI way of doing this, but not sure what that would be (maybe write to the NIFI cache?).

--S

Comment: Content is stream of UTF-8 encoded messages. As I encounter parse errors in a downstream processor (say Processor 3), I want to reference the original unmodified raw stream.

Comment: Do you have anything in the message you can key off off? Like a unique identifier of some kind? If so, you could use the PutDistributedCache might be a good option.  You could then retrieve the original content from the cache, when needed.